# waitpid stops waiting after signal is sent

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I am currently working on a C project for university. Among other things I should signal the parent process using `SIGUSR1`.
The problem I'm facing at the moment is that I also need to wait for the child process to terminate so I can safely shut down everything in the end (removing shared Memory etc.).

At the moment I am using `sigaction()` to respond to the signal and `waitpid()` to wait for the child to terminate (that was the plan anyways ^^). But when I signal the parent using `kill()`, `waitpid()` stops waiting and runs the remainder of the parent even though the child is still running.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
stay safe

Tim

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handle_sigusr1(int sig) {
  printf("Recieved signal %i.\n", sig);
}

int main() {
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1) {
    perror("fork:");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  else if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Hello from the child.\n");
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    sleep(3);
    printf("Hello again from the child.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  else {
    printf("Hello from the parent.\n");
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigusr1;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
      printf("Exit status: %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    printf("Finished waiting for child.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello from the parent.
Hello from the child.
Recieved signal 10.
Exit status: 0
Finished waiting for child.
tim@schlepptop:signalTest$ Hello again from the child.
```

PS: `WEXITSTATUS(status)` is usually `0` but sometimes it's also something like `16` or `128`.

Comment: If you read the man page for waitpid it says "they block until either a child changes state or a signal handler interrupts the call "

Comment: that makes sense now. Is there any alternative to wait only for the termination of the process and not the signal?

Comment: Adding to the previous comment - check the return value of `waitpid` and react accordingly by calling `waitpid` again or exiting. Alternatively, set `SA_RESTART` when installing the sighandler.

Comment: Ok, ill try that and post a solution if i find it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @kaylum `SA_RESTART` does not guarantee that all calls will be restarted.  The [list on the Linux `sigaction()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), for example, is not all-inclusive, although in this case it does list `waitpid()`.  There's also a list of functions that will never be restarted.  `waitpid()`, for example, is [***not*** documented as being restarted on Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37841/sigaction-2.html).  `SA_RESTART` is useful, but it's not a catch-all.

Comment: OT, but likely to cause intermittent problems:  `struct sigaction sa;` should be cleared before being used with `memset( &sa, 0, sizeof( sa ) );`.  Else you have no idea what's in the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [POSIX `waitpid()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html#tag_16_645_04):

> ***RETURN VALUE***
>
> ... If `wait()` or `waitpid()` returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, `-1` shall be returned and `errno` set to `[EINTR]`. ...

You need to check the return value:

```
int status
do
{
    errno = 0;
    int rc = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if ( rc != -1 )
    {
        break;
    }
}
while ( errno == EINTR );
```